# Customizing the add button in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I wonder if there is a method to customize the normal "+" button in the `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd` method.

This is my current code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;
    [addButtonItem release];
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: What kind of customization are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did to a 3rd party TableView package was creating my own UIBarButtonItem and settig the target & action properties to the ones of the original button. In some cases this will work and in some cases it won't (like if the target checks the source-object for a specific object) - but it's worth a try!

Comment: Martin, you are the man. I never thought that would work, but it does - beautifully. Thank you so much. David

Answer (score 2):

Except for the `style` property, you can't alter a bar button created in such fashion. If you are looking for other customizations, your best bet is `initWithImage:style:target:action:`.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. That's what I was afraid of, as I'm using a custom TableView package, I don't think I have access to the selector. @Remy, I just to change the name of the button to "Add".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to Martin. I thought it might be useful to show the code.

Instead of :

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;
    [addButtonItem release];
```

I simply used this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                  target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [buttons addObject:addButton];
    [addButton release];
```

Comment: Ok how do yo assign an action to this button now?

Comment: change action:nil to action:@selector(doSomethingUseful:). doSomethingUseful: would be a new method.